# OpenTok video get zoomed or distorted on iphone 5s,iphone 5,ipod 5

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, tokbox

We are using openTok in iOS application for video broadcast were user can broadcast live video to other user.
On publisher end the cameraResolution is high // AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 and when the user from iPhone 6s or iphone 6s plus publish the video and on other hand subscriber receive the video on iphone 5s,iphone 5,ipod 5  the video get zoomed or distorted.
Please let me know if anyone faced same issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm dealing with the same problem